# Laravel Http Client events not firing from terminal

Tags: laravel, event-handling, subscriber

I created a subscriber that listen to Http Client events (ConnectionFailed, ResponseReceived) to log all http requests. It works fine when I make a request in controller, but when I make a request in tinker or in a command, nothing will log.
Do you have any idea what's the problem?

But it works in a fresh Laravel.

I tried `chmod -R 777 storage/logs`

Adding

```
public function shouldDiscoverEvents()
{
    return true;
}
```

to EventServiceProvider.
Adding `APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug` to  .env
Also

```
sudo rm -rf storage/framework/cache/data/*
sudo rm -rf bootstrap/cache/*
composer dump-autoload
php artisan clear
php artisan debugbar:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan auth:clear-resets
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:forget spatie.permission.cache
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the imanghafoori/laravel-microscope package caused this issue.
I created an issue: https://github.com/imanghafoori1/laravel-microscope/issues/161